# Remove white color programatically from image in Xcode project using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I have the following JPG image in my iOS project:

[image]

I want to remove all the white color programatically from it using Swift to make the background transparent and save it as PNG.

I know how to save the image as a PNG in another folder, but I still don't know how to remove the white color from the image.

There is any library or piece of code that I can use

Any ideas of how to do that?

EDIT:

Following @DuncanC suggestion, I update the code from Github and try to use it.

I try to manipulate the image using the following code

```
let a:UIImage = imagemSubViewPrincipal.image!
let rgbImage:RGBAImage = RGBAImage(image: a)!
for piece in rgbImage.pixels {
    print("\(piece.green) - \(piece.red)  - " )
}
```

EDIT #2:

```
for piece in rgbImage.pixels {
  if piece.red >= 250 && piece.green >= 250 && piece.blue >= 250 {
    print("\(piece.red) - \(piece.green) - \(piece.blue) - \(piece.alpha)" )
    piece.alpha = 0
  }
}
```

I received the following error:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'piece' is a 'let' constant
```

How can I create a new image with alpha value changed to 0.

EDIT #3:

I was able to make it work using the code below.

I was able to get a transparent image.

```
for (index, piece) in rgbImage.pixels.enumerated()  {
        if piece.red >= 240 && piece.green >= 240 && piece.blue >= 240 {
            rgbImage.pixels[index] = transparentPixel
        }
    }
```

[image: transparent image]

External link to image
https://snipboard.io/oGOb08.jpg

I was able to change white pixels to another color, just like in the example below

[image: image with yellow background]

I just change the transparent pixel to

```
let transparentPixel = Pixel(value: 0x00000000)
let yellowPixel = Pixel(value: 0xFF00FFFF)
```

@DuncanS Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Define the thing that you so-call 'the white color.'  If you are talking about eliminating every pixel whose hex value is #FFFFFF, show what you have done so far.

Comment: Yes, 'the white color' can be defined as the hex value of #FFFFFF, but the only thing that I do is create an image using - let myImage = UIImage(named: "frente_cabeca_cavalo") -. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You can't change values you fetch in a for loop like that. Use `for (index, piece) in rgbImage.pixels.enumerated()`, and then when you find a pixel you need to change, use code like `rgbImage.pixels[index] = transparentPixel` (Where you define `transparentPixel` with a value of 0 before beginning the loop.)

Comment: If you try to print out every white pixel you will generate almost 10,000 lines of console output, and your code will take **hours** to run.

Comment: I remove the print statement from my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to convert your image to RGBA pixel data, look for all white pixels, and force their alpha channel to 0.

A little googling revealed [**this gist on github**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOm0e.gif). It defines a struct called RGBAImage that you initialize with a UIImage, and contains an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` to RGBA pixel data.

You should be able to convert your image to an RGBAImage, then loop through the image data looking for white pixels and forcing their alpha to 0. You will need to decide if you only want to "knock out" pure white pixels with R/G/B values of 255/255/255, or if you want some "slop" in your matching of white pixels. You might want to set the alpha of pixels that are almost white to be almost transparent, so you have some feathering of the nearly-white to nearly-transparent.

I'd start by just knocking the alpha of 255/255/255 pixels to 0 and see how that looks. If you want some feathering you can try adding it.

### Edit:

I decided to play with this a little, and found that the code at that Github link is badly out of date. I've converted it to Swift 5 syntax. Here it is:

```
import UIKit

public struct Pixel {
    public var value: UInt32

    public var red: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8(value & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = UInt32(newValue) | (value & 0xFFFFFF00)
        }
    }

    public var green: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 8) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (value & 0xFFFF00FF)
        }
    }

    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 16) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (value & 0xFF00FFFF)
        }
    }

    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 24) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (value & 0x00FFFFFF)
        }
    }
}

public struct RGBAImage {
    public var pixels: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>

    public var width: Int
    public var height: Int

    public init?(image: UIImage) {
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }

        // Redraw image for correct pixel format
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue

        width = Int(image.size.width)
        height = Int(image.size.height)
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.allocate(capacity:width * height)

        guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: imageData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else { return nil }
        imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

        pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)
    }

    public func toUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue

        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: pixels.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, releaseCallback: nil, releaseInfo: nil) else { return nil }

        guard let cgImage = imageContext.makeImage() else {return nil}
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

        return image
    }
}
```

### Edit #2:

In playing with your image, I found that the white pixels are not pure white. If you attempt to match R/G/B values of 255/255/255, they don't match. I used code that looked for values >250 in all 3 color channels, and that worked.

I also found that I had to replace the pixel value with 0x00000000. Setting the alpha channel value to 0 did not force the pixels to transparent for some reason. (I think it has to do with the fact that the data is in premultipliedLast mode, which I don't fully understand.)

### Edit #3:

Here is what the demo app I came up with looks like:

Try your hand at it using the updated code I posted. If you get stuck let me know and I can help.

[image]

### Edit #4:

In your code from your updated question, you tried to modify the Pixel values fetched by your for...in loop. That won't work. You can't change values you fetch in a for loop like that. Use a for loop like this:

```
let transparentPixel = Pixel(value: 0x00000000)
for (index, piece) in rgbImage.pixels.enumerated()  {
    // Your code to check and modify pixels
}
```

and then when you find a pixel you need to change, use code like

```
rgbImage.pixels[index] = transparentPixel
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I try the code that you recommended to me on Github, but it's really out of date and I was not able to use it. I will try again now since you update the code. and try to follow your guidelines.

Comment: Can you share the demo app that you created on Github or other place? This is what I was looking for. I edit my question based in your answer.

Comment: You'll learn more if you make your code work. Once you get yours working, Post your working code as another answer and I'll upload my demo app to github and post a link.